# Checking if an array only has a specific set of numbers

Tags: c

My goal was to replicate a poker game, and here I want to see if I found any "pairs" in a hand, and return the count. However, if I get a three-of-a-kind or a four-of-a-kind, even though those have a pair and 2 pairs respectively, I technically do not have any "pairs". My code finds pairs, trips, and quads properly, however, if it finds a three-of-a-kind or four-of-a-kind, it also finds a pair when it should not. How can I fix my code to prevent that?

M represents how many cards I am checking, and the unsigned char hand[] is an array of my hands with each hand being an 8-bit character

```
int pairs(int M, unsigned char hand[]) { // 8 bits (top 4 represent card, bottom 4 represent suit)
    int pairCount = 0;
    int pairCheck = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < M; j++) {
            
            if ((hand[i] & 0xF0) == (hand[j] & 0xF0)) { // checks the card values (top 4 bits of character in array)
                pairCheck++;
            }
        }
        if (pairCheck == 2) {
            pairCount++; 
        }
        pairCheck = 0;
    }
    return pairCount;
}

int trip_s(int M, unsigned char hand[]) {
    int tripsCount = 0;
    int tripsCheck = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            
            if ((hand[i] & 0xF0) == (hand[j] & 0xF0)) { // checks the card values (top 4 bits of character in array)
                tripsCheck++;
            }
        }
        if (tripsCheck == 3) {
            tripsCount++; 
        }
        tripsCheck = 0;
    }
    return tripsCount;
}


int four_kind(int M, unsigned char hand[]) {
    int quadsCount = 0;
    int quadsCheck = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            
            if ((hand[i] & 0xF0) == (hand[j] & 0xF0)) { // checks the card values (top 4 bits of character in array)
                quadsCheck++;
            }
        }
        if (quadsCheck == 4) {
            quadsCount++; 
        }
        quadsCheck = 0;
    }
    return quadsCount;
}
```

Comment: You didn’t post any code that actually has to do with your issue. Four of a kind _is_ a pair. If you don’t want it to be counted you will have to properly order and short circuit your code where you’re actually calling these methods.

Comment: Which version of poker is this?

Comment: This should be much simpler if you used a `std::map<char, int>`, where the key is the card and the `int` is the count.  Then you simply populate the map (no need for all of these separate functions such as `four_kind`).  Then you have right there one data structure (the map) that gives you all the information you need.

Comment: As to how simple using a map would be: `void populate_map(unsigned char* hand, int M, hand_map& hm){ hm.clear(); for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) hm[hand[i] >> 4]++;}` -- That's the entire function to populate the map.  You now know by traversing the built-up map the number of pairs, three of a kind, etc.  with no ambiguities, no "double counting pairs", etc.  Now before posting this as an answer -- are you allowed to use `std::map` or similar data structure?

Comment: The assignment was designed to strictly use these three functions separately as they are called in loops in the main to test each hand of 7 cards

Answer (score 2):

Missing a main loop but assuming you are checking for all pairs.

You should add something to check if a four of a kind is found

so if (four_kind(m, hand) > 0) then skip checking the rest same for three of a kind